# Maintain Slide.Name when copying slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint

At [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slide.name), the official documentation says of the Slide.Name property says:

> If you copy a slide from one presentation to another, the slide loses the name it had in the first presentation and is automatically assigned a new name in the second presentation.

I can see the rationale for this. However, I am now trying to implement a procedure which guarantees unique names. Specifically, in the first presentation, I run this code:

```
Dim last As Long: last = GetLastSlideNumber("LastSection")

Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To last

    With ActivePresentation.Slides(i)
        Dim newName As String: newName = "new" & i
        .Name = newName
    End With

Next
```

which names all the slides in this presentation as new1, new2, etc. Then, I run similar code in the other one to name the slides as old1, old2, etc.

Now, I have guaranteed that the names are unique. Is there any way I can leverage off this to copy slides over **without** losing the slide name?

Comment: Seems when done manually the slide name resets to "Slide#". So you'd still have to reset the name after copying, it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Try maybe do it trough the event class

```
' AppEvents class module
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub App_PresentationNewSlide(ByVal Sld As Slide)
    Sld.Parent.Slides(Sld.SlideIndex).Name = "MyuniqueSlideName#Number"
End Sub
```

Then you call from Module1

```
' Module 1
Option Explicit

Public pApp As AppEvents

Sub GetAppClass()
    Set pApp = New AppEvents
    Set pApp.App = Application
End Sub
```

After that, every time you add new slide the App_PresentationNewSlide will occur.